# Swap images on 2 buttons with a click of another button

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, swap

I have 2 buttons with an image on each, i want that with a click of another(third) button the images of previous 2 buttons are swapped. I have tried this but i'm getting some kind of error. Plz help. My code is:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class SwapImage implements ActionListener
{
JButton b1;
JButton b2;
JButton b3;
ImageIcon bgi1;
ImageIcon bgi2;
ImageIcon bgi3=new ImageIcon();

SwapImage()
{
JFrame f=new JFrame("Swap Image");

bgi1=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("a.png"));
bgi2=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("b.png"));

b1=new JButton(bgi1);
b1.setBounds(80,80,100,100);
//b1.addActionListener(this);

b2=new JButton(bgi2);
b2.setBounds(200,80,100,100);
//b2.addActionListener(this);

b3=new JButton("SWAP");
b3.setBounds(170,230,100,100);
b3.addActionListener(this);

f.add(b1);
f.add(b2);
f.add(b3);
f.setSize(400,400);
f.setLayout(null);
f.setVisible(true);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

bgi3=bgi1;
bgi1=bgi2;
bgi2=bgi3;
b1=new JButton(bgi1);
b2=new JButton(bgi2);

}


public static void main(String s[])
{
new SwapImage();
}

}
```

Comment: What is some kind of error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your actionPerformed, don't call:

```
b1=new JButton(bgi1);
b2=new JButton(bgi2);
```

instead, just set the icons:

```
b1.setIcon(bgi1);
b2.setIcon(bgi2);
```

Comment: @AkshatMalviya I'm glad to help. If this solution solved your problem, you should mark it as correct to let other volunteers know that an accepted answer has already been provided, saving people's time by not opening/reading questions that already have an answer.